# Suppress "Do you want the browser to remember..."-WebView window?

Tags: android, webview

I'm automatically signing users into a login-form using JavaScript within a `WebView`. Once the form is (automatically) submitted, the ususal "Do you want the browser to remember this password?" appears, which I would like to suppress, as the login should happen automatically.

I have tried
`webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);`

to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using

`webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);`

which (in my opinion) is pretty counter-intuitive, but gets the job done, as it specifically *doesn't* request the user to save the form data (and also doesn't save it).

Comment: I doesn't seem counter intuitive to me anyways thanks for the answer